# How to use UIDocumentPickerViewController to import files in iOS 16

Tags: swift, xcode, uikit, ios16, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller

I was trying to use the UIDocumentPickerViewController to import some pdf files in my Swift UIKit App. I'm not able to properly use the `UIDocumentPickerViewController` to display the files app and import the files from there.

The initialiser `UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: [String], in: UIDocumentPickerMode)` was deprecated in iOS 14.0. I can still use it but is there a better way to do the same thing which is not deprecated and is used in the latest version of iOS?

Comment: Start by looking at the list of initializers in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentpickerviewcontroller).

Comment: @HangarRash I have already done that. The initializer "init(forOpeningContentTypes: [UTType])" is showing up in the Apple Documentation(which is probably the required one for me) but I'm not able to use it. When I type it out, Xcode says "This static method is defined on UIDocumentPickerViewController, and may not be available in this context."

Comment: That's definitely the correct initializer. Try it and see if it compiles. Update your question with details as needed.

Comment: @HangarRash Tried to dig more into it and found a thread that said we had to import "UniformTypeIdentifiers". It's ridiculous how Apple doesn't even show a warning or anything about it.

Answer (score 0):

Importing "UniformTypeIdentifiers" seems to enable the "init(forOpeningContentTypes: [UTType])" initializer.